# Standardise data for a spider plot in relation to a control variable

Tags: r, standards, normalization, radar-chart

I am trying to standardise a series of data so that I can plot the data in a radarplot where my control condition is 0 and the treatment varies between +1 and -1.  The final figure should look like

[image]

Previous questions on the same topic do not involve to fix the value of all variables to 0 for one factor.

An example of my data is:

```
data<-structure(list(genID = c("gen01","gen01", "gen01", "gen01","gen01", "gen01", "gen01", "gen01", "gen01", "gen01", "gen01","gen01", "gen01", "gen01", "gen01"), 
                     trt = c("C", "C", "C", "C","C", "N-", "N-", "N-", "N-", "N-", "P-", "P-", "P-", "P-", "P-"), 
                     param = c("t_for_Fm", "Area", "Fo", "Fm", "Fv", "t_for_Fm","Area", "Fo", "Fm", "Fv", "t_for_Fm", "Area", "Fo", "Fm", "Fv"), 
                     value = c(530, 37621.75, 298, 1271.75, 973.75, 460, 37006.6666666667,437.666666666667, 1460, 1022.33333333333, 408, 36293.6, 350.4,1415.2, 1064.8)), 
                  row.names = c(NA, -15L), 
                  class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In these data I would like to set the C as 0 and then have the variation of N- and P- relitevely to it.

A code that partly worked till now was:

```
data%>%
pivot_wider(names_from = trt,
          values_from = value)%>%
mutate(`N-`=`N-`/C, `P-`=`P-`/C, C=C/C)%>%
filter(time==6 & genID=="gen04")%>%
select(param, C, `N-`, `P-`)%>%
t()%>%
as.data.frame()%>%
row_to_names(row_number = 1)%>%
rownames_to_column(var = "group")%>%
as.data.frame()%>%
dplyr::mutate_at(vars(t_for_Fm:F5_to_Fm), as.numeric)%>%
ggradar(
values.radar = c("-1", "1.5", "3"),
grid.min = -1, grid.mid = 1.5, grid.max = 3,
# Polygons
group.line.width = 1, 
group.point.size = 3,
group.colours = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
background.circle.colour = "white",
gridline.mid.colour = "grey",
legend.position = "bottom"
)
```